# Media Storage System Message on Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, media, system-configuration

We are utilizing the database media storage feature on our **Magento 2.2** site.  We ran the synchronization and got the following system message.

*We were unable to synchronize one or more media files. Please refer to the log file for details.*

[image]

I have two question about this message.

1. What log is it talking about?  I would like to see which if any images had problems syncing over.   I've looked around in `var/log` but haven't found any reference.
2. How do you clear this system message?  It's not present in the `System > Notifications listing.`